# Modbus: convert hex value to dword in nodejs

Tags: node.js, hex, dword

Specification given in the manual of meter which uses modbus as communication protocol:

```
“dword” refers to 32-bit unsigned integer using two data addresses and 4 bytes
of memory with high word at the front and low word at the end, it varies from 0
to 4294967295. rx = high word *65536+low word
```

i have this hexValue : `00003ef5`.

where `highword = 0000`
and `lowword = 3ef5`

so rx would be `3ef5` and this converted to decimal gives `16,117`.

For now i have used this:

```
var rx = hexValue.substr(0,4)*65536 + hexValue.substr(4,8);
console.log(parseInt(rx,16));
```

Is there a way to convert my hex value directly to dword using nodejs buffer library or any other method better than this?

Comment: Is there any solution to this, I have this c code `(BYTE*)&buf[0]` and I want to convert it to javascript. I used buffers but how to cast it to `BYTE` or `WORD` or `DWORD`.